# AbstractExcelView returning empty document

Tags: spring-mvc, abstractexcelview

I'm creating a service call to grab data from our database and download it as an Excel file. When I call the service, I get a file to download, but it's empty when I open it! I don't see any errors in my logs, in fact, my logger makes it appear everything is fine.

**Excel Builder**

```
public class PromotionExportExcelBuilder extends AbstractExcelView {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model, HSSFWorkbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        List<PromotionRequestDTO> promoCodes = (List<PromotionRequestDTO>) model.get("promoCodes");

        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(promoCodes)) {

            ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();

            // create style for header cells
            CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
            Font font = workbook.createFont();
            font.setFontName("Arial");
            style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.BLUE.index);
            style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
            font.setColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
            style.setFont(font);

            Integer totalPromos = promoCodes.size();
            logger.debug(totalPromos + " promo codes are being exported");
            Integer numberOfSheets = 1;

            // Only want a set number of codes per sheet
            if (totalPromos > PromotionMicroServiceBusinessConstants.PROMO_RECORDS_PER_SHEET) {
                numberOfSheets = (totalPromos / PromotionMicroServiceBusinessConstants.PROMO_RECORDS_PER_SHEET ) + 1;
            }

            logger.debug(numberOfSheets + " sheets will be needed");

            for (int sheetNumber = 1; sheetNumber <= numberOfSheets; sheetNumber++) {
                logger.debug("Making sheet number " + sheetNumber);
                HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Promotion Codes Sheet " + sheetNumber);
                sheet.setDefaultColumnWidth(30);

                HSSFRow header = sheet.createRow(0);
                header.createCell(0).setCellValue("CAMPAIGN");
                header.getCell(0).setCellStyle(style);
                header.createCell(1).setCellValue("PROMO CODE");
                header.getCell(1).setCellStyle(style);

                int rowCount = 1;

                /*
                  CODE TO FILL OTHER ROWS. CURRENTLY COMMENTED OUT FOR TESTING
                */

                logger.debug("Sheet number " + sheetNumber + " created");

            }

            workbook.write(output); // Actually write the workbook.
        }
    }

}
```

Then when I look at the logs, I see this:

```
28-Jun-2017 17:55:08.122 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 10904 ms
17:55:15.031 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'promocode' processing GET request for [/promocode-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/rest/exportPromotionCodes]
17:55:15.038 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /exportPromotionCodes
17:55:15.041 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.otc.promotion.controller.PromotionController.exportPromotionCodes(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)]
17:55:15.041 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'promotionController'
17:55:15.046 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/promocode-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/rest/exportPromotionCodes] is: -1
17:55:15.069 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  c.o.p.controller.PromotionController - Request to Export promotion codes for campaign[17] and batch [null]
17:55:15.293 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'promotionExportView'
17:55:15.294 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [com.otc.promotion.views.PromotionExportExcelBuilder: name 'promotionExportView'] in DispatcherServlet with name 'promocode'
17:55:15.414 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG c.o.p.v.PromotionExportExcelBuilder - Created Excel Workbook from scratch
17:55:15.425 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG c.o.p.v.PromotionExportExcelBuilder - 30 promo codes are being exported
17:55:15.426 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG c.o.p.v.PromotionExportExcelBuilder - 1 sheets will be needed
17:55:15.426 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG c.o.p.v.PromotionExportExcelBuilder - Making sheet number 1
17:55:15.512 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG c.o.p.v.PromotionExportExcelBuilder - Sheet number 1 created
17:55:15.574 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

And when I open the downloaded file, I see this:

[image: Empty Excel File]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the issue. It's not an issue with the REST call at all. My Excel is messed up and opens an "empty" application whenever I click on an Excel file. If I open the file from Microsoft Excel, I see the data.